# Arithmetic that takes three command-line arguments and output required as java Arithmetic: 3 + 2 = 5

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

```
class CommandLineArgs {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int l = args.length;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      sum = Integer.parseInt(args[j]) + sum;
    }
    System.out.println("The Sum of All Elements entered at command line is : " + sum);
  }
}
```

I tried using arguments but not able to do in using function as my required output is a=number1 and b=number2 and c=operator (+,-,/,*). Please help me in writing the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a case or if statement.

```
if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("+")
{
   sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
}
else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
{
   sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

you can use array for this

```
        String[] arr= new String[l]; create a string array

        for(int j=0;j<l ;j++){

        arr[j] = args[j];// first of all store all inputs in the array

            }
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
// then iterate over the array and check for the last char of array
        if(arr[2].equalsIgnoreCase("+"){
         sum = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) + Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
       System.out.println("The Sum of All Elements entered at command line is : " + sum);
        }else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("*")
        {
           code for multiplication
        }

          }
```